# Update method from script doesn't called

Tags: unity

After experiments with Unity versions, I have reproduced Mandelbrot example from scratch and got `C#` script doesn't called. If I set breakpoint, it says it is not reacheable

[image]

I think I set up all links. As it seem from IDE hint, inheritance is correct.

[image]

Simultaneously, shader is working, i.e. image is displayed, but not updated by controller.

Comment: What object in your scene has an instance of the Explorer script attached to it? Can you show us how that scene object is configured?

Comment: This was it, sorry, thanks